# How to save data from http request using codeigniter restful

Tags: web-services, codeigniter, rest, restful-authentication

I am using **restful** to create the web-service for my android app. I have login with Facebook button in my app and I want to store the user data from their Facebook account.

```
public function sotrefacebookuser_get(){
    $data[] = base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
    if(!empty($data) && $data != ""){
        $userid = $this->Api_model->savefacebookuser($data);

        if(!empty($userid)){
            $this->response(array('status'=>'success', 'massage'=> 'Your Record Save successfully'));
        } else {
            $this->response(array('status'=>'failure', 'massage'=> 'The specified data could not saved try again letter'), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->response(array('status'=>'failure', 'massage'=> 'The specified data could not be found'), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

The above code is my **API** controller which is working fine but I know, this is not the proper way to do it.

and this is my Model code.

```
public function savefacebookuser($data){
    $this->_table = "front_user";
    return $this->insert($data, FALSE);
}
```

how to use the post method in restful to save data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In restful if you want to save data you need to use post request and send the data in body.

```
public function sotrefacebookuser_post(){
    $data = $_POST['key'];
    if(!empty($data) && $data != ""){
        $userid = $this->Api_model->savefacebookuser($data);

        if(!empty($userid)){
            $this->response(array('status'=>'success', 'massage'=> 'Your Record Save successfully'));
        } else {
            $this->response(array('status'=>'failure', 'massage'=> 'The specified data could not saved try again letter'), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->response(array('status'=>'failure', 'massage'=> 'The specified data could not be found'), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```